# Why is CouchDB view's total_rows different to offset when no rows are found?

Tags: database, key, couchdb

When calling a CouchDB view with a key I get no results, but the total_rows is different to the offset.

This surprises me as I thought that the offset was the index of when the first document that matched the view key was found. Clearly this is not the case.

My URL:

```
http://foutonURL/dbName/_design/designDocName/_view/viewName?key=%226696%22
```

The response:

```
{"total_rows":2716,"offset":2612,"rows":[

]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there are no entries in the view that match the given key, the `offset` value is the index into the view where the entry would be if it had the desired key. Essentially, CouchDB is saying this is where I went to find the entry for the given key, but there was nothing there.

Comment: But ... why then is it not the LAST row? surely it needs to check all the way to the last row to confirm no match? From the answer it sounds like Couch is guessing at the most appropriate place to 'imagine' a key would have been. I'm not following ...

Comment: The view entries are stored in a btree, enabling fast, efficient lookup. This also means that when looking for a key it can quickly locate the leaf node it would be at if it existed. No guessing needed.